# Adding column to dataframe and updating in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark:

```
ratings = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.textFile("transactions.json").map(lambda l: json.loads(l)),
)
ratings.show()

+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+
|click_id|         created_at|          ip|product_id|product_price|user_id|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+
|     123|2016-10-03 12:50:33| 10.10.10.10|     98373|        220.5|      1|
|     124|2017-02-03 11:51:33| 10.13.10.10|     97373|        320.5|      1|
|     125|2017-10-03 12:52:33| 192.168.2.1|     96373|         20.5|      1|
|     126|2017-10-03 13:50:33|172.16.11.10|     88373|        220.5|      2|
|     127|2017-10-03 13:51:33| 10.12.15.15|     87373|        320.5|      2|
|     128|2017-10-03 13:52:33|192.168.1.10|     86373|         20.5|      2|
|     129|2017-08-03 14:50:33| 10.13.10.10|     78373|        220.5|      3|
|     130|2017-10-03 14:51:33| 12.168.1.60|     77373|        320.5|      3|
|     131|2017-10-03 14:52:33| 10.10.30.30|     76373|         20.5|      3|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+

ratings.registerTempTable("transactions")
final_df = sqlContext.sql("select * from transactions");
```

I want to add a new column to this data frame called `status` and then update the status column based on `created_at` and `user_id`.

The `created_at` and `user_id` are read from the given table `transations` and passed to a function `get_status(user_id,created_at)` which returns the `status`. This `status` needs to be put into the transaction table as a new column for the corresponding `user_id` and `created_at`

Can I run alter and update command in pyspark?
How can this be done using pyspark ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want to do exactly. You should check out `window functions` they allow you to compare, sum... rows in a frame.

For instance

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("user_id").orderBy(psf.desc("created_at"))
ratings.withColumn(
    "status", 
    psf.when(psf.row_number().over(w) == 1, "active").otherwise("inactive")).sort("click_id").show()

+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
|click_id|         created_at|          ip|product_id|product_price|user_id|  status|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
|     123|2016-10-03 12:50:33| 10.10.10.10|     98373|        220.5|      1|inactive|
|     124|2017-02-03 11:51:33| 10.13.10.10|     97373|        320.5|      1|inactive|
|     125|2017-10-03 12:52:33| 192.168.2.1|     96373|         20.5|      1|  active|
|     126|2017-10-03 13:50:33|172.16.11.10|     88373|        220.5|      2|inactive|
|     127|2017-10-03 13:51:33| 10.12.15.15|     87373|        320.5|      2|inactive|
|     128|2017-10-03 13:52:33|192.168.1.10|     86373|         20.5|      2|  active|
|     129|2017-08-03 14:50:33| 10.13.10.10|     78373|        220.5|      3|inactive|
|     130|2017-10-03 14:51:33| 12.168.1.60|     77373|        320.5|      3|inactive|
|     131|2017-10-03 14:52:33| 10.10.30.30|     76373|         20.5|      3|  active|
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------+-------------+-------+--------+
```

It gives you each user's last click

If you want to pass a `UDF` to create a new column from two existing ones. 
Say you have a function that takes the `user_id` and `created_at` as arguments

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def get_status(user_id,created_at): 
    ...

get_status_udf = psf.udf(get_status, StringType())
```

`StringType()` or whichever datatype your function outputs

```py
ratings.withColumn("status", get_status_udf("user_id", "created_at"))
```

Comment: The `created_at` and `user_id` are read from the given table `transations` and passed to a function `get_status(user_id,created_at)` which returns the `status`. This `status` needs to be put into the transaction table as a new column for the corresponding `user_id` and `created_at`